# Caching the blur event using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to do something when a blur event is fired from a text box.

The problem is the blur event is also fired when the user presses the "Enter" key
and when the mouse is clicked somewhere else.

I need to do some specific action when the mouse is clicked somewhere else; how would I do it?

Comment: I'm not clear here; can you say which blur events you actually want and which you don't want?

Comment: both when the user presses the enter key, the blur event is fired via script and when the user clicks somewhere on the document the blur event is fired by the js engine, i want to catch the both but do different things on both type of events

Answer (score 1):

This might also help:

Set timer that delays the blur event action before it fires the button click event.

// Namespace for timer var setTimer = { timer: null }

```
    $('input,select').blur(function () {
        setTimer.timer = setTimeout(function () {
           functionCall();
        }, 1000);
    });

    $('input,select').focus(function () {
        setTimer.timer = setTimeout(function () {
            functionCall();
        }, 1000);
    });

    $("#btn").click(function () {
        clearTimeout(setTimer.timer);
        functionCall();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a way:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<input id="txtbox" ><input>

<script>

$(document).click(function()
                    {
                      if($('#txtbox').data('blurred')==1)
                      {
                        $('#txtbox').data('blurred',0);
                        alert('blurred by click');
                      }
                    }
                  );

$('#txtbox').blur(function(e)
                  { var _this=this;$(_this).data('blurred',1);
                    setTimeout(function(){$(_this).data('blurred',0);} ,200);
                  }
                 ).unbind('click');

</script>
```

It uses a flag(named 'blurred', stored inside the input's data).

So if the blur-event fires, this flag is first set to 1 and a moment later set to 0(this moment should be enough for click to fire before). If click fires on document, it just checks this flag.